# Can't connect to wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I can't connect to my wifi network with Xubuntu 16.04. I use an Acer Aspire E5-573-54HH with Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter. I tried to connect with Network Manager and it's asking repeatedly for the password. So I tried Wicd. When I try to connect I get the error message that the password is wrong. Until yesterday I had Windows 10 on this laptop and it worked perfectly. How can I get more information and solve this problem?

Until Ubuntu 15.10 there were problems with the wifi adapter and the firmware. The user had to install it manually. With Ubuntu 16.04 it should be installed directly so that I can find my network with properties like channel and security settings but I can't connect. Even if I set the securtiy to none and try to connect I can see in Wicd that there is an unsecured network and password is wrong. Strange.

Finally I tried an Edimax Wifi USB Stick (back with network-manager) and it works. But I prefer to use my intern wifi card.

```
 $ iwconfig
 wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
           Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:on

 enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

 lo        no wireless extensions.

 wlx801f02e4a8fd  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Gljja"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: 00:17:9A:6F:FC:FB   
           Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:off
           Link Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3714   Missed beacon:0

 $ dmesg | grep wlp3s0
 [   16.973819] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
 [   23.974863] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
 [   25.886916] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
 [   29.998944] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
 [   62.996019] wlp3s0: authenticate with 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb
 [   63.039736] wlp3s0: send auth to 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (try 1/3)
 [   63.041261] wlp3s0: authenticated
 [   63.041408] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [   63.041412] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [   63.042042] wlp3s0: associate with 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (try 1/3)
 [   63.044123] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
 [   63.045580] wlp3s0: associated
 [   63.045612] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
 [   66.731076] wlp3s0: disassociated from 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (Reason: 3)
 [   74.658881] wlp3s0: authenticate with 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb
 [   74.701802] wlp3s0: send auth to 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (try 1/3)
 [   74.703335] wlp3s0: authenticated
 [   74.703501] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [   74.703504] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [   74.705913] wlp3s0: associate with 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (try 1/3)
 [   74.707983] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
 [   74.709876] wlp3s0: associated
 [   77.884261] wlp3s0: disassociated from 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (Reason: 3)
 [   80.430329] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready

 $ dmesg | grep wlx801f02e4a8fd
 [   99.498664] rtl8192cu 2-2:1.0 wlx801f02e4a8fd: renamed from wlan0
 [   99.529120] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx801f02e4a8fd: link is not ready
 [   99.924207] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx801f02e4a8fd: link is not ready
 [   99.961862] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx801f02e4a8fd: link is not ready
 [  118.058355] wlx801f02e4a8fd: authenticate with 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb
 [  118.080625] wlx801f02e4a8fd: send auth to 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (try 1/3)
 [  118.099749] wlx801f02e4a8fd: authenticated
 [  118.099934] rtl8192cu 2-2:1.0 wlx801f02e4a8fd: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [  118.099939] rtl8192cu 2-2:1.0 wlx801f02e4a8fd: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [  118.101826] wlx801f02e4a8fd: associate with 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (try 1/3)
 [  118.205854] wlx801f02e4a8fd: associate with 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (try 2/3)
 [  118.247341] wlx801f02e4a8fd: RX AssocResp from 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
 [  118.347487] wlx801f02e4a8fd: associated
 [  118.347496] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx801f02e4a8fd: link becomes ready

 $ dmesg | grep ath10k[   13.823372] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
 [   14.546304] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
 [   16.653947] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 11ad:0806) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
 [   16.653955] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
 [   16.973819] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
 [   63.041408] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [   63.041412] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [   66.846535] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   66.846829] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   67.051342] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   67.153714] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   67.256116] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   67.358519] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   68.236463] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   68.382577] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   68.484971] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   68.587389] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   74.703501] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [   74.703504] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
 [   78.007234] ath10k_warn: 12 callbacks suppressed
 [   78.007248] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   79.544039] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   79.646432] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   79.748817] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   79.851341] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   79.851477] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   80.058047] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [  108.727056] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [  363.692698] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [ 3072.853880] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [ 3261.599501] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [ 4080.691326] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [ 4521.829086] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [ 4836.667286] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

Answer (score 0):

Please start by updating the firmware:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if you connect.

In your log, we see:

```
wlp3s0: disassociated from 00:17:9a:6f:fc:fb (Reason: 3)
```

According to this, 'reason 3' means; "Deauthenticated because sending STA is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS"

http://www.aboutcher.co.uk/2012/07/linux-wifi-deauthenticated-reason-codes/

I wonder if that is because your router is set to use auto channel selection, rather than a fixed channel. Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: I updated from 1.157 to 1.161 but it didn't help. Can't connect.

Comment: Please find your wireless interface: `iwconfig` Next, check the log for clues: `dmesg | grep <interface_you_found>` As the result will be lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Intern wifi is wlp3s0.  Edimax is wlx801f02e4a8fd. http://paste.ubuntu.com/23540687/

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: The router has no auto channel. Channel 6 is configured with WPA2-AES. The router is a D-Link DI-524. It's not capable of N speed. I can set G-mode or mixed mode. I set the regulatory domain. All this didn't help.

Don't forget. The same laptop with the same wifi card and the same router works with Win 10 and not with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Although the hardware is the same, the driver (software) is entirely different. I regret that I haven't any other suggestions.